# CSS DIV as table - how to make all column same height as the highest

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have some problems with my DIV table.. maybe there is a better way to do this.

I want to have all columns to be the same height as the highest column. Is there a way to do it? or is there another way to make this work ?

I have to made a jsfiddle example here with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/rb500o4L/ (right column is higher than left, middle and the logo column.)

My CSS code:

```
div.round-border {
border: solid 1px;
border-color: #002F67;
border-radius: 10px;
}  

#container {
display: table;
width: 100%;
}

#row  {
display: table-row;
}

#cell {
display: table-cell;
}

#cell-logo {
display: table-cell;
width: 200px;
}
```

My HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="row">

<div id="cell">
    <div class="round-border">
        <h4>Left Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="cell">
    <div class="round-border">      
        <h4>Middle Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>  
</div>

<div id="cell">
    <div class="round-border">      
        <h4>Right Col</h4>
        <p>...</p>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="cell-logo">
    <div class="round-border">
        <h4>LOGO AREA</h4>
        <p>...</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I appreciate any recommendation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this css

```
div.round-border {
border: solid 1px;
border-color: #002F67;
border-radius: 10px;
  }  

 container {

width: 100%;
}

 row  {

height:auto;


 }

  #cell 

 {
height:auto;
min-height:400px;
width:50px;
  display:inline-block;

  }

 #cell-logo {

  width: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: thank you Abdul Basit, but i want to make it dynamic. This means that the higehest column could be higher or small than 200px.

Comment: set height auto and min height to 200px it will dynamically change

Comment: and set the row height to auto as well